# Why I cant initialize a Channel using Vue?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, getstream-io

I am having trouble when I'm trying to initialise a Channel. 
I've followed some tutorials provided (https://getstream.io/blog/chat-messaging-with-laravel/, https://getstream.io/blog/tutorial-build-customer-support-chat-with-laravel-vue-and-stream/) that have a stack as mine (Laravel + Vue)

I am already getting the token on the backend, initializing the Client, setting the User and the token on the client.

But when I try to do `this.channel.watch();` or even a simple channels query like

```
const filter = { type: 'messages', id: '1000056864'};
                const sort = { last_message_at: -1 };
                const channels = await this.client.queryChannels(filter, sort, {
                    watch: true,
                    state: true,
                });
```

It will return to me the error as follows:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://chat-us-east-1.stream-io-api.com/channels/messages/1000056864/query?user_id=62&api_key=2e******e2&connection_id=5983f850-3d50-4ac3-9c06-d9e0fdaf7212' from origin 'http://local.site.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-csrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Everything is working on the backend, even the equivalent calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you are receiving, it looks like you are including your CSRF token to all your AJAX requests. Stream API servers have a whitelist of headers that you can pass, this is to safe developers from sending sensitive data by accident. In this specific case it is arguable that `csrf-token` could be in such whitelist for the sake of ease of use.

Perhaps you are using something like this on your frontend?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

If that's the case my suggestion is to opt for a more fine grained solution such as:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: "/laravel/",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Or make sure that only your Laravel backend receives the CSRF token by extracting JS code doing Ajax calls.

CSRF tokens are not as valuable as session IDs but they exist to make your application more secure and are not meant to be shared with 3rd parties.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to change the header settings on the Stream client? Or other settings, like timeout...